# Get inserted data without submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Simply can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I want to get the newly inserted data with jQuery when a user leaves the input field.

```
<textarea rows="3" id="textArea" data-atr="23,mytest,se"></textarea>
```

It work if I have something predefined text in the box, but not if it's just inserted text.

Here is what i have done so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $("#textArea").blur(function(){

        var atr = $("#textArea").data("atr");

        var temp = new Array();
        temp = atr.split(",");

        var thisText = $("#textArea").html();

        console.log(temp[0]+' - '+temp[1]+' - '+temp[2]+' - '+thisText);
    });

});
```

My console log looks like this after I have written something into the field:
**23 - mytest - se -**

The inputted text is not there? What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use val() instead of html().

Your existing code..

```
var thisText = $("#textArea").html();
```

You should use..

```
var thisText = $("#textArea").val();
```